# Get row number from cell reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula, row

If cell `A1` contains `'Sheet1'!A5`, how can I extract the row number (5)?

If I do `=ROW(A1)`, it will return `1`, instead of `5`. How do I get `5` instead?

Comment: `=ROW(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(A1),"=","")))` ? (If `A1` contains a _Formula_, otherwise, what Ron said)

Comment: `=ROW(INDIRECT(A1))`